# Python Decimal Places *easy*

Tags: python

I feel a bit blonde right now, but for some reason I can't figure out how to solve this.

Need to correct these two issues.

1. using // integer division messes up the average.
2. Also, I need to use the format function to get 2 decimal places

   def viewscores(scores):

   ```
   sum_scores = sum(scores)
   average = float(sum_scores // len(scores))
   ### here is where I am having the results displayed

   print ("The scores are these: " + str(scores))
   print ("The Average score now is: " + str(average))
   ```

   def main():

   ```
   scores = []

   scores_file = open('scores.txt', 'r')
   line_list = list(scores_file.readlines())

   scores_file.close()
   i = 0
   while i < len(line_list):
       scores.append(int(line_list[i].strip()))
       i += 1
   viewscores(scores)
   ```

   main()

Comment: If `sum_score` is an integer, then make it a float before you divide it by an integer. Mess around with dividing with integers, and you will see why.

Comment: Don't use _floored_ division. [Format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those things where Python2 and Python3 behave differently.

> using // integer division messes up the average.

Python 3:

```
average = sum_scores / len(scores)
```

Python 2:

```
average = float(sum_scores) / len(scores)
```

In either case, you don't want to use `//`.

> Also, I need to use the format function to get 2 decimal places

Python 3:

```
print ('The average score now is {:.2f}'.format(average))
```

Python 2:

```
print ('The average score now is %.2f' % average)
```

Even within each dialect there's multiple solutions.

Comment: Don't forget that you can make Python 2's `/` operator behave like Python 3's with `from __future__ import division`.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple option would be to use `format(scores, '.2f')`

```
sum_scores = float(sum(scores))
average = (sum_scores / float(len(scores)))


print ("The scores are these: %s" %format(scores, '.2f'))
print ("The Average score now is: %s"  %format(average, '.2f')
```

Answer (score 0):

i am new to Python as well.

For "//", i gave a trial on ipython, to me they do not make much difference whether you use // or /

- using "/" http://screencloud.net/v/hcDo
- using "//" http://screencloud.net/v/bwAq
- the solution to your request is  http://screencloud.net/v/rwQp

For two decisoinal place problem, i learnt something from the following

- [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)
- and it works to your case  - http://screencloud.net/v/1gPB

For function, you may wish to consult Google

- i am not good at creating function, but function always should have "return", because everything in python is object